# CSS render image top of the background color

Tags: css

I've to follow below HTML structure.

```
 <a class="abc" style: {background:"blue"}">
        <img  src="ImgPath" />
    </a>
```

CSS

```
.abc{
    width: 177px;
    height: 177px;
    display:inline-block;
}
abc img {
    display:block;
    z-index:9999;
    width:50px;
    height:50px
}
```

I want to display transparent image on top of the background color. I shouldn't use background-image/background: #c1c1c1 url('img.png') no-repeat; css property. I don't want use image as background-image. Image is hiding of background color.

Any help?

Comment: What do you mean by `on top of the tag`? Sorry but it's unclear what you ask, at least to me.

Comment: Transparent image doesn't hide background color...btw you syntax is not correct while writing `style` attribute.

Comment: Your html should be `<a class="abc" style="background:blue"><img src="ImgPath" alt="something" /></a>`

Comment: I've added alt for image, but no use :(

Answer (score 1):

The image is probably not showing because you have unclosed quotes:

```
<a class="abc" style: {background:"blue"}">
```

You should have:

```
<a class="abc" style="background:blue">
```

Better to use CSS

```
.abc {
    background: url("ImgPath") 0 0 no-repeat blue;
}
```

Comment: I shouldn't use background-image/background: #c1c1c1 url('img.png') no-repeat; css property. I don't want use image as background-image.

Answer (score 0):

You can give an elment a background color and set a background image like this:

CSS

```
.abc{ 
background: #c1c1c1 url('path/img.jpg') no-repeat;
}
```

HTML

```
<a class="abc"></a>
```

This way the color is not hided.

Comment: I shouldn't use background-image/background: #c1c1c1 url('img.png') no-repeat; css property. I don't want use image as background-image.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking something this kind of effect?

Not sure you are looking this kind of stuff. check Demo link. http://jsbin.com/wibaxuyu/1/

```
a.abc{
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  background:rgba(145 ,145 ,89 ,00.5);
  display:inline-block;
  position:relative;
}
a img{
  position:absolute;
  top:20%;
  left:20%;
    z-index:9999;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
   opacity: 0.8;
   filter: alpha(opacity=80); /* IE 5-7 */
  -moz-opacity: 0.8;
}

<a class="abc">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100" />
</a>
```

Comment: Are you looking this kind of stuff, check the Demo link. http://jsbin.com/wibaxuyu/1/

Comment: doesn't this help you?